# Cake php validation for percentage,Not accept numeric characters and Spacial characters

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I want cake php validation for tax percentage numeric field,In that field accept only numeric character like 5.00.Not greater than 100 and not accept spacial character.I try some pattern but it will not work on spacial character like,(!#$%^).My demo code is

```
$this->validate['TaxPercent'] = array(
        'pattern' => array(
                'rule'    => '/^[\0-9]+$/',
                'allowEmpty' => true,
                'message' => __('err__numberfield', array(__('lbl_TaxPercent', true))), 
            ),
        'notEmpty' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                'message' => __('err_required', array(__('lbl_TaxPercent', true))), 
            ),
        'decimal' => array(
                'rule' => array('decimal', 2),
                'allowEmpty' => true,
                'message' => __("lbl_TaxPercentValid", array(__('lbl_TaxPercent', true))),
            ),
        'range' => array(
                'rule' => array('range', 0, 101),
                'allowEmpty' => true,
                'message' => __("err__percentage", array(__('lbl_TaxPercent', true))),
            )
        );
```

So please suggest me appropriate solution.

Comment: instead of pattern did you try using rule => "numeric", since you only accept numeric. Can you also update your question like, make a list of your accepted inputs? Your question is not clear enough regarding the special characters.

Comment: Field accept only numeric characters and not greater than 100, not accept spacial character.

Comment: try my answer below, there's a validation rule for that "numeric"

Comment: i think you can also remove the numeric part because you have already specified below that its  a decimal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED AND WORKING**

```
  $this->validate['TaxPercent'] = array(
    'notEmpty' => array(
            'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
            'message' => __('err_required', array(__('lbl_TaxPercent', true))), 
        ),
    'decimal' => array(
            'rule' =>  array("decimal", "2",  '/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/') //this is working
            'allowEmpty' => true,
            'message' => __("lbl_TaxPercentValid", array(__('lbl_TaxPercent', true))),
        ),
    'range' => array(
            'rule' => array('range', 0, 100.01), //updated this one to so its only until 100.00
            'allowEmpty' => true,
            'message' => __("err__percentage", array(__('lbl_TaxPercent', true))),
        )
    );
```

Comment: 12.00 not accept.I think both decimal and numeric not work at a time.

Comment: I try this but it give range validation on spacial character. In case i enter spacial character into field.

Comment: what special character are you entering on the field?

Comment: @user3804333 This is a validation with regex and working! :) Check it out. Marked it as correct anwer if it really did work!

Comment: Both answer working correct in all condition but in spacial character it give message "Tax percentage not greater than 100%".

Comment: In my part, when I enter a special character like, #$%, it returns error that it must be a decimal. can you double check my answer?

Comment: Which data type u can use??

Comment: I added this rule  'rule' =>  array("decimal", "2",  '/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/') on the decimal